# "[PAClient Error] Error: E0776" - PARAMETER_ERROR.INVALID

Tags: xcode, app-store, rad-studio, paserver

When I deploy an app from RAD Studio 11.0 to Xcode 13.2.1 on a remote macOS machine, through PAServer, I get following error:

```
[PAClient Error] Error: E0776 2022-03-01 11:05:28.836 xcodebuild[3909:39218] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path "/var/folders/6z/jy_wjt2d3hb9lq_62gylf28w0000gn/T/AppSV_2022-03-01_11-05-28.835.xcdistributionlogs".
[PAClient Error] Error: E0776 error: exportArchive: The operation couldn’t be completed. (IDEFoundation.DistributionAppRecordError error 3.)
[PAClient Error] Error: E0776 IDEFoundation.DistributionAppRecordError.buildNumberRequestFailed(DVTAppStoreConnect.BuildsService.Error.responseErrors(ResponseErrors (1): Error status: 400, code: PARAMETER_ERROR.INVALID, title: 'A parameter has an invalid value', detail: ''' is not a valid filter', id: 31f7ef8f-86ac-4ecd-9e00-821ab4152791))
[PAClient Error] Error: E0776 ** EXPORT FAILED **
```